# Connecting to 2 Wifi Networks ? One with Internet, the other one with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: 18.10

I said pretty much everything in the title: for a personnal project, I would need my personnal laptop running Ubuntu 18.10 to be able to access Internet via my internal Wifi Adapter, and to my Raspberry Pi via an external USB Adapter (or the other way around). Is it only possible ? And if so, how is the setup ?

Answer (score 0):

**There is a nice tool** out there that is able to this in an easy way. I use it frequenly. Check out  [**Create_AP**](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap). Install all it's dependencies.

Instead of `haveged` i use `rng-tools` with my raspberries [How to install rng-tools for your raspberry pi](https://scruss.com/blog/2013/06/07/well-that-was-unexpected-the-raspberry-pis-hardware-random-number-generator/).

**Keep an eye on** `dmesg -w` to check if you might have any **voltage issues**.  A lot power supplies are insufficient to generate enough power with so many usb devices attached to the raspberry.

If you need a step by step guide, i can write one for you, but i guess the github page is self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Another method is described at the Raspberry Pi website under documentation > configuration > wireless > access-point

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md